# Selecting rows based on a number of orders

Tags: select, segment, orders

My table `PURCHASES` has the following columns: `NAME`, `ORDER_ID`, `ITEM_ID`.

When a client orders 2 items, it is recorded with 2 rows under same ORDER_ID and two identical or different ITEM_ID (depending if the customer has bought the same items or not).

I would like to select all the clients who made a total of less than 3 orders and less than 4 items (regardless if they are identical). Here is the current code:

```
SELECT NAME, COUNT(DISTINCT ORDER_ID) AS number_of_orders, COUNT(ITEM_ID) AS number_of_items
FROM `PURCHASES`
WHERE number_of_orders <3
AND number_of_items <4
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY number_of_items DESC
```

I get the following error message: `Unknown column 'number_of_orders' in 'where clause'`

Comment: you cannot have a derived column alias name in the where clause , select clause items are defined at the end of the query execution. 
use "Where  COUNT(DISTINCT ORDER_ID) > 3 " instead

Comment: same with the number_Of_items.

Comment: Hi Prashant: I get "Invalid use of group function"

Comment: Have posted the answer check that, even where clause will not work with grouped by values.. you have to use Having clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query

```
SELECT NAME, COUNT(DISTINCT ORDER_ID) AS number_of_orders, COUNT(ITEM_ID) AS
number_of_items
FROM `PURCHASES`
GROUP BY NAME
HAving COUNT(DISTINCT ORDER_ID) <3
AND COUNT(ITEM_ID) <4
ORDER BY number_of_items DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it with a subquery

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT NAME, COUNT(DISTINCT ORDER_ID) AS number_of_orders, COUNT(ITEM_ID)   AS number_of_items)
FROM `PURCHASES`
WHERE number_of_orders <3
    AND number_of_items <4
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY number_of_items DESC
```